# Remove unformatted text except all except elements?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that contains an unformatted text and two divs. If you ask why the text isn't formatted it's because it's returned by a plugin through the API so I can't really control it. The markup looks like so:

```
<div id="parentdiv">
   <div class="childdiv"></div>
   <div class="childdiv"></div>
   unformattedtext
</div>
```

How do I get rid of "unformattedtext"? If possible I would like to do it with CSS but if not it's okay with jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This removes text-nodes which are direct childs of `#parentdiv`:

```
$("#parentdiv").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; }).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#parentdiv').contents(':not(*)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put `unformattedtext` into a div/a/p/span/font with `display:inline`, so as not to break formattion.

```
<div id="parentdiv">
    <div class="childdiv"></div>
    <div class="childdiv"></div>
    <div style="display:inline">unformattedtext</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#parentdiv :not(.childdiv)").hide(); //Hide whatever is not .childdiv
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kongr45gpen/EBL4G/